# How to modify an XML file present in a folder in the Silverlight project?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read & modify an XML file present in the Silverlight project from a view's code behind.

This is how I've read & modified the XML file:

```
StreamResourceInfo s = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("XML/Settings.xml", UriKind.Relative));

XElement doc = XElement.Load(s.Stream, LoadOptions.None);

IEnumerable<XElement> settingElement = (from b in doc.Descendants(
                                             "setting")
                                           select b).Take(1);
if (settingElement.Count<XElement>() > 0)
{
    foreach (var node in newsIdNode)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
}
```

What I want to do now, is to save the XML file. I tried the following:

```
doc.Save(s.Stream, SaveOptions.None);
```

But got a runtime error that the stream is not writable.

How can I save changes to this XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't- the stream is only for reading. If you want to save something consider [isolated storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29), [saving to a file](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) or persisting state [via Web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645029%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you please give some example of these three ways, or provide some links? @RichardOD